# mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Tags: php

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\goblins2.php on line 13

LINE 13:`$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);`

**Código:**

```
<?php
$host_db = "localhost";
$user_db = "u_gringottsDB1";
$pass_db = "i";
$db_name = "gringottsDB";
$tbl_name = "Goblins";
/*$conexion = new  PDO("mysql:host=$host_db; dbname=$db_name","$user_db", "$pass_db");*/

try{
    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$host_db; dbname=$db_name","$user_db", "$pass_db");
    /*$sentencia1 = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE goblin_name = '$_POST[username]' ");*/
    $result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE goblin_name = '$_POST[username]' ");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($count == 1) {
        echo "<br />". "L'usuari ja existeix" . "<br />";

    }else{
        $form_pass = $_POST['password'];
        $hash = password_hash($form_pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
        $sentencia = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO $tbl_name (username, password) VALUES(:username, :password)");
        $sentencia->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sentencia->bindParam(':password', $_POST['password'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sentencia->execute(); 
        echo "Inserció realitzada";
    }
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo 'Fallo la conexion:'.$e->GetMessage();
}
```

Comment: hazle var_dump() a tu consulta
 Utiliza el web inspector del navegador para ver el query que esta ejecutando luego ejecutalo en tu gestor de bd para ver en que te estas equivocando

Answer (score 2):

En el código se aprecia claramente que estás usando PDO para conectar a la base de datos:

```
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=$host_db; dbname=$db_name","$user_db", "$pass_db");
```

Pero en la línea donde ocurre el error usas la función `mysqli_num_rows` para obtener el número de filas.

```
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Esa función es de `mysqli`, no de PDO. Son dos cosas totalmente distintas.

En PDO, el método que cuenta el total de filas es [`rowCount()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.rowcount.php). Pero, hay que tener muy en cuenta lo que dice el Manual de PHP (ver sobre todo el **Ejemplo 2** del Manual):

> Si la última sentencia SQL ejecutada por el objeto PDOStatement
>   asociado fue una sentencia `SELECT`, algunas bases de datos podrían
>   devolver el número de filas devuelto por dicha sentencia. Sin embargo,
>   este comportamiento no está garantizado para todas las bases de datos
>   y no debería confiarse en él para aplicaciones portables.

Por tanto, la forma más segura es hacer un `SELECT COUNT(*)` y obtener el total de filas con `fetchColumn`.  Otro problema en tu código es que la consulta es vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*. No sé por qué motivo renunciaste a la consulta preparada que aparece comentada en el código, cuando era la vía correcta de proceder.

Con este código podrás obtener el total de filas, aplicando un método seguro en todos los sentidos:

```
//...
try{
    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$host_db; dbname=$db_name","$user_db", "$pass_db");
    $sentencia = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM $tbl_name WHERE goblin_name =: goblin_name ");
    $sentencia->bindParam(':goblin_name', $_POST['username'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sentencia->execute(); 
    $count = $sentencia->fetchColumn();

    if ($count == 1) {
        echo "<br />". "L'usuari ja existeix" . "<br />";

    }else{

    //... resto del código

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo indagar en la documentación oficial de php , y como dice mi compañero ejeuta un `var_dump` o `print_r` para ver que te esta devolviendo mysql, pero además te dejo esto para que lo intentes

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT Code, Name FROM Country ORDER BY Name")) {

    /* determinar el número de filas del resultado */
    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

    printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row_cnt);

    /* cerrar el resultset */
    $result->close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema esta en el `where` de tu `select` ya que no esta obteniendo bien la variable del `$_POST` 
Ejemplo:

```
try{
    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$host_db; dbname=$db_name","$user_db", "$pass_db");
    /*$sentencia1 = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE goblin_name = '$_POST['username']' ");*/
    $result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE goblin_name = '".$_POST["username"]."' ");
    if($result){
        $count = $result->fetchColumn();//mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if ($count == 1) {
            echo "<br />". "L'usuari ja existeix" . "<br />";

        }else{
            $form_pass = $_POST['password'];
            $hash = password_hash($form_pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
            $sentencia = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO $tbl_name (username, password) VALUES(:username, :password)");
            $sentencia->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sentencia->bindParam(':password', $_POST['password'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sentencia->execute(); 
            echo "Inserció realitzada";
        }
    }
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo 'Fallo la conexion:'.$e->GetMessage();
}
```

Comment: Eso y el hecho de que esta mezclando PDO con mysqli